# Setting MdiParent from child form

Tags: c#, winforms, mdiparent

I have a principal form that contains a menu to open child form:

```
public Le_MainForm()
{ 
  InitializeComponent();
  this.IsMdiContainer = true;
  .....
}

private void barButtonItem_CreatOrdreAller_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
  Close_AllForm();
  Program.StatusOrdre = 1;
  Program.AllerRetour = "Ordre Aller";
  Fiche_Ordre f_Fiche = new Fiche_Ordre();
  f_Fiche.MdiParent = this;
  f_Fiche.Show();
}
```

It works well, but I open another form from child, I lost MdiParent:

```
public Liste_Ordres()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  ....
}

private void Liste_DobleClic(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Fiche_Ordre f_Fiche = new Fiche_Ordre(gridView_Liste_Ordres.GetFocusedRowCellValue("NO_ORDRE").ToString());
  f_Fiche.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: It's not very clear where Liste_Ordres is coming from since your MDI Child form is a type Fiche_Ordre.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the form like this:

```
Fiche_Ordre f_Fiche = new Fiche_Ordre(gridView_Liste_Ordres.GetFocusedRowCellValue("NO_ORDRE").ToString());
f_Fiche.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
f_Fiche.Show();
```

`ShowDialog()` is for a pop-up modal form.